# Impala escape character

Tags: character, impala

How to handle square bracket in case statement in Impala.

Hi ALl,

I am having a case statement like below.

```
Case when action ilike ['XYX','ABC'] then 0
     WHEN action ilike ['select'] THEN 4
     WHEN action ilike ['read', 'execute'] THEN 4
   ELSE 0
```

while executing in am getting undefined exception.

Comment: what is  your logic for this ?  is it action  like '%XYZ%' or  '%ABC%' ? if yes, you need to change the syntax

Comment: ['read', 'execute']  this is my single string which i am getting from upstream. Now i have to set their status based on this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls escape single quote using `\` and try?

```
Case when action ilike '[\'XYX\',\'ABC\']' then 0 
   ELSE 0
```